# What are the differences between tf.initialize_all_variables() and tf.global_variables_initializer()

Tags: tensorflow

On Tensorflow official website, it gives explantions of the `tf.initialize_all_variables()` and `tf.global_variables_initializer()` functions as follow

> #### tf.initialize_all_variables():
>
> Returns an op that initializes all variables.
>
> #### tf.global_variables_initializer():
>
> Adds an op to initialize all variables in the model

It seems like both can be used to initialize all variables in graphs. Can we use these two functions exchangbly? If not, what would be the differences?

Comment: global variables will be removed in TensorFlow 2.0, so both will be deprecated soon.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Unfortunately, you forgot to read an important line in the documentation of [`tf.initialize_all_variables`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/initialize_all_variables).

> THIS FUNCTION IS DEPRECATED. It will be removed after 2017-03-02. Instructions for updating: Use `tf.global_variables_initializer` instead.

Answer (score 4):

The [changelog for 0.12 version](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/RELEASE.md#release-0120) tells you that both both functions do the same thing because:

> tf.initialize_all_variables renamed to tf.global_variables_initializer

and as Martianwars mentioned the documentation for [initialize_all_variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/initialize_all_variables) tells that:

> THIS FUNCTION IS DEPRECATED. It will be removed after 2017-03-02.
>   Instructions for updating: Use tf.global_variables_initializer
>   instead.

If you will call it, you will get a warning as well. So you should always use `tf.global_variables_initializer()`