# What is the difference in global_variables_initializer() and initialize_all_variables()?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In Tensorflow, what is the difference in `global_variables_initializer()` and `initialize_all_variables()`? I had used both methods to initialize the variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between tf.initialize\_all\_variables() and tf.global\_variables\_initializer()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41439254/what-are-the-differences-between-tf-initialize-all-variables-and-tf-global-var)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/initialize_all_variables), you will see that they do the same, but `tf.initialize_all_variables` is now deprecated in favour of `tf.global_variables_initializer`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't check it out but according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40220201/tensorflow-tf-initialize-all-variables-vs-tf-initialize-local-variables) and my personal experience from code in previous versions of tensorflow `initialize_all_variables()` used to initialize both global and local variables when was not deprecated but in recent version (where it's considered deprecated) it's just a (deprecated) equivalent to `global_variables_initializer()`.

So, depending on the version it might change the answer.